# Get rid of letters that are in string 1 in string 2 and then combine the new string 2 with string 1

Tags: python

I thought I solved this problem but then my solution also removed letters in string 1.
Here are some inputs and outputs that I want to achieve:

a, bcdefg, into abcdefg.   ab, cdefgic, into abcdefgi.   abc, adefghiad, into abcdefghi.   hello,world, into hellowrd. troy, warrior, into troywai.   frizzy,wizzo, into frizzywo.   stops,potts, into stops. stops,potts111, into stops1. stops,potts222, into stops2. jokes,bedazzling into jokesbdazling

Also please explain your solution if you can.

Comment: str1 being the first text, then the comma, then str2 being the next text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str1 = "abc"
str2 = "arabdcd"

letters_list = list(str1+str2)
letters = []

for l in letters_list:
    if l not in letters:
        letters.append(l)
new_string = "".join(letters)
```